# URLCache caches URL on Xcode simulator but not device

Tags: ios, xcode, afnetworking, alamofire

My URLCache caches URLs in Xcode simulator, but not on a real device. I narrowed the code down to this example:

```
if let urlCache = SessionManager().session.configuration.urlCache {

    // Returns nil, because there's nothing in the cache
    print(urlCache.cachedResponse(for: urlRequest))

    // Put the URL in the cache
    urlCache.storeCachedResponse(CachedURLResponse(response: response, data: responseData), for: urlRequest)

    // URL should now be in the cache, but it's still nil!
    print(urlCache.cachedResponse(for: urlRequest))
}
```

I'm very confused by this. Any ideas?

Comment: Out of curiosity, what is the size of the `responseData`? What is the `diskCapacity` and `memoryCapacity` of your `urlCache`?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out this cache was being populated by other network calls and running out of space. We fixed it by dramatically increasing the size of the cache.

Answer (score 0):

`URLCache.storeCachedResponse()` is likely an asynchronous method and the following  line might not behave as you expect because the `urlRequest` is not yet available in the cache

```
print(urlCache.cachedResponse(for: urlRequest))
```